# Property binding doesn't work as expected

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I'm trying just now to implement a list with complicated data. In my case it should be an array like this:

```
[
    { item: "itemName1", objects: [x1,x1,x1] },
    { item: "itemName2", objects: [x2,x2,x2] }
]
```

As I know there are 2 ways to do that. First of them is to expose QObjectList-based model from C++ to QML. Than currently not interested for me since I want to implement that in pure QML. But ListElement's roles must contain only simple constants, line strings, numbers etc. i.e. no arrays.
So I did the data source as external array:

```js
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0


Window {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    id: window
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 2
        spacing: 2
        property var data: [ { name: "item1", objects: [1,2,3]} ]
        model: data.length
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height:  content.height
            property int itemIndex: index
            color: index % 2 ? "#EFEFEF" : "#DEDEDE"
            RowLayout {
                id: content
                spacing: 10
                Text {
                    text: listView.data[itemIndex].name
                }
                Column {
                    Repeater {
                        model: listView.data[itemIndex].objects.length
                        Text {
                            text: listView.data[itemIndex].objects[index]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            listView.data.push( { name: "item2", objects: [4,5,6] } );
            listView.data.push( { name: "item3", objects: [7,8,9] } );
            listView.model = listView.data.length; // it doesnt't work without this line
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine with static array. The problem appears when I fill the array dynamically. In this case the property binding (model: data.length) suddenly stops working. So the workaround is to set it manually but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Why do you have to do it in pure QML?

Comment: [By design](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html#change-notification-semantics). I remember a similar question and a proposed answer, which was probably a workaround.

Comment: That isn't real project. I just want to find a efficient and least-cost way to perform specified task. Thanks @BaCaRoZzo, I just thought about reasigning the array with new value. But actually I don't like this workaround since this operation could be too expensive with a big array. So, I think I'll stay with my decision

Comment: I've been trying to get a solution, but I cannot find a proper way to solve your issue. I have [this](https://gist.github.com/7b49ad42534552ddd509.git) but I think is different from you have in your mind.